# youtube live chat show only on desktop - on mobile see nothing

Tags: youtube, chat, live

I used the following iframe to embed youtube live chat:

If you try to see the embeded chat you see regurarly on desktop version:
https://visionforex.info/market-news/

If you try to see it on mobile I only see a blank space.

My question is: is it possible to show youtube live chat on mobile ? 
Are there any limit? I have seen on internet that youtube don't allow live chat on mobile if you don't have an ADSense account. We have a Google ADS account on the web site.

Any suggestion is very appreciated!
Many thanks in advance

Marzio

I tried to put the iframe directly into the page and not into widget but nothing changed.

I followed all suggestion find out on stack overflow without success.

Comment: <iframe class="widgetcomment" src="//youtube.com/live_chat?v=cnpZAXE0CoI&embed_domain=visionforex.info" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>

Comment: I would imagine that the iframe is calling unsecured elements which hinders the video from rendering cross site or your YouTube chat requires that you enable some type of setting to embed it correctly. I cannot get your iframe to load from my localhost at all, but I can view the site from my browser

Comment: Hi Via Tech. Did you tried to see on mobile? With chrome you can see mobile version but you have to reload the page and you will see nothing

Answer (score 0):

It says YouTube Chat embed is not possible on Mobile, only on Desktop browsers:

> Note: embedding live chat isn't available on mobile web.
>
> During a live stream, you can embed live chat on your own site by
>   using an iframe.
>
> Get the video ID for the live stream. You can get the video ID from the watch page URL (youtube.com/watch?v=12345). In this case, the video ID is ‘12345’. If you chose "Stream now," right-click on the player and select Copy video URL to get the video URL.
>
> Get the domain URL for the site you want to embed chat on. If you're embedding chat on www.example.com/youtube_chat, your embedding domain is "www.example.com."
>
> Combine the embedded URL in the following way: https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=12345&embed_domain=www.example.com
>
> This is the URL for your iframe. Note the embed_domain must match the URL of the page you’re embedding the chat on. If they are different, the embedded chat will not load.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2524549?hl=en